# Getting requested page route in Nuxt middleware

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js, vue-router

I have a very simple 'named' Nuxt middleware set up (taken from the docs) which checks in the store to see whether a user is authenticated before they can navigate to certain routes. If the user is not authenticated, they are directed to a straightforward form in which they have to provide an email address to gain access (at `http://example.com/access`). All of that works fine, after they fulfil the middleware's `store.state.authenticated` check they can navigate around no problem.

```
export default function ({ store, redirect }) {
  if (!store.state.authenticated) {
    return redirect('/access')
  }
}
```

My question is, once the user *has* entered their email address, I have no way of knowing what route they were **initially** trying to access. I've looked at other questions here about [passing data between routes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50998305/vue-is-there-a-way-to-pass-data-between-routes-without-url-params) but because of the way the middleware works these solutions don't seem to be feasible.

I really would rather not set the slug in the `vuex` state as this will lead to a whole other set of complications – I also don't mind setting the intended slug as a query or a param on the `/access` url. I have [read through the docs](https://nuxtjs.org/api/context/#-code-redirect-code-em-function-em-) for the Nuxt `redirect` function and realise you can pass a `route.query` as an argument. So it seems that you could potentially do something like this:

```
return redirect('/access', intendedSlug)
```

...or, if using params(?):

```
return redirect(`/access/${intendedSlug}`)
```

But I don't know how to pass that `intendedSlug` value to the middleware in the first place as it's not exposed on the `context` passed to the function or anywhere else. It seems like this would be a common problem, but I can't find any simple solutions – any help would be really appreciated!

Comment: Did you ever figure this out? I've got the exact same problem and have not found anything that might help!

Comment: Hey @bodger, i've posted an answer for you :-)

Answer (score 0):

To help @Bodger I'm posting how I resolved this, it may not be perfect and it's working on a slightly older version of Nuxt (I know !) but this is how I resolved the issue.

`.../middleware/authenticated.js`

```
export default function (context) {
  const path =
    context.route.path.length && context.route.path[0] === '/'
      ? context.route.path.slice(1)
      : context.route.path
  const pathArray = path.split('/')
  if (process.server && !context.store.state.authenticated) {
    return context.redirect('/access', pathArray)
  } else if (!context.store.state.authenticated) {
    return context.redirect('/access', pathArray)
  }
}
```

The `pathArray` is then accessible in my `/access` page.

`.../pages/access.js`

```
data() {
    return {
      attemptedRoutePathArray: Object.values(this.$route.query)
      ...
    }
  },
...
computed: {
    attemptedRouteURL() {
      return new URL(
        this.attemptedRoutePathArray.join('/'),
        process.env.baseUrl
      )
    },
    ...
}
```