# is the way of pass data with JSON.stringfy correct way?

Tags: vue.js

I just started a vue.

I want to send an object array from homeView to SampleView.
After searching some information, I used JSON.stringify() and was able to get the data.

The data form I want to send is like below

```
words: [
    { key: "key", word: "test-name", definition: "test-definition", text: '' },
    { key: "key", word: "test-name", definition: "test-definition", text: '' },
    { key: "key", word: "test-name", definition: "test-ddd", text: '' },
]
```

```
<v-btn size="small" :to="{ name: 'WordGame', query: {gameWords: JSON.stringify(words)}}" class="float-right">단어 게임</v-btn>
```

what I'm curious about is that it is normal way to send an object data by query string?

And what way could I make code better?

---

HomeView.vue

```
<template>
  <div class="ma-5">
    <v-row>
      {{ this.date }}
    </v-row>
    <v-row justify="end">
      <v-btn size="small" class="float-right me-1" @click="hideDefinition">{{ hideButton }}</v-btn>
      <v-btn size="small" href="/words/new" class="float-right me-1" v-if="isToday">추가하기</v-btn>
      <v-btn size="small" :to="{ name: 'WordGame', query: {gameWords: words} }" class="float-right">단어 게임</v-btn>
    </v-row>
  </div>
</template>
```

SampleView.vue

```
<template>
  <div class="ma-5">
    <v-row
        v-for="word in gameWords"
        :key="word.key"
    >
      <v-col>
        <v-card
            :text="word.word"
        >
        </v-card>
      </v-col>
      <v-col>
          <v-text-field v-model="word.text">

          </v-text-field>
      </v-col>
    </v-row>

    <v-row class="me-1" justify="end">
      <v-btn @click="submit">
        제출
      </v-btn>
    </v-row>
  </div>
</template>

<script>

export default {
  mounted() {
    this.init();
  },
  props: ['gameWords'],
  methods: {
    init() {
      console.log(this.$route.query.gameWords)
    },
  }
}
</script>
```

router.js

```
const router = createRouter({
    history: createWebHistory(),

    routes: [
        {
            path: '/word-game',
            name: 'WordGame',
            component: () => import('../views/SampleView.vue'),
            props: true
        },
    ]
});
```

App.vue

```
<template>
  <v-app>
    <v-main>
      <v-container>
        <voca-header></voca-header>
        <router-view></router-view>
      </v-container>
    </v-main>
  </v-app>
</template>
```

Comment: Why not just `:to="{ name: 'WordGame', query: {gameWords: words}}"`…?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Vue, is there a way to pass data between routes without URL params?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50998305/vue-is-there-a-way-to-pass-data-between-routes-without-url-params)

Comment: @deceze I've been tried the way. But it only shows "[object Object]"..

Comment: @Wimanicesir Unfortunately, it doesn't solve my problem. My output is  "[object Object]" with the first method in the link

Comment: You can use global store to pass data through the app

Comment: @EstusFlask Is it a good way to set global data for one page? I'm a newbie But for me, it seems unnatural..

Comment: Global store is a way to exchange data through the app. So generally, yes. It's less unnatural than exposing internal data in url because the router cannot work in another way. On the other hand, if you want data to be persisted when this url is reopened, e.g when a browser crashed, then use a query

Answer (score 0):

You can assign words directly, no need to use `JSON.stringify`

```
:to="{ name: 'WordGame', query: {gameWords: words} }"
```

Output

```
{ "name": "WordGame", "query": { "gameWords": [ { "key": "key", "word": "test-name", "definition": "test-definition", "text": "" }, { "key": "key", "word": "test-name", "definition": "test-definition", "text": "" }, { "key": "key", "word": "test-name", "definition": "test-ddd", "text": "" } ] } }
```

Also, There are different possible ways to pass the props but I would suggest passing the data separately, e.g:

```
<v-btn size="small" name='WordGame' :gameWords={words}" class="float-right">단어 게임</v-btn>
```

OR

```
<v-btn size="small" name='WordGame'  query={gameWords: words} class="float-right">단어 게임</v-btn>
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer ! I tried the way u directed, But the output is http://localhost:8089/word-game?gameWords=[object+Object]

Comment: Okay, I thought you wanted to pass props in another component.Can you please share the full code? So everyone can get a clear idea.

Comment: I added my full code. Thank you !

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to expose your parameters in the url, you can pass parameters using the router's **`params`** property.

```
<v-btn size="small" :to="{ name: 'WordGame', query: {gameWords: words} }" class="float-right">단어 게임</v-btn>
```

Change query to name

```
<v-btn size="small" :to="{ name: 'WordGame', params: {gameWords: words} }" class="float-right">단어 게임</v-btn>
```

In `SampleView.vue` you should use params to receive parameters.

```
export default {
  mounted() {
    this.init();
  },
  props: ['gameWords'],
  methods: {
    init() {
      console.log(this.$route.params.gameWords)
    },
  }
}
```